# Problem with rule condition that depends on another rule action

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, drools, reactive

I'm facing some problems with Drools. When I try to set some boolean in one action and then evaluate this on another "when", is not already updated. I already have a workaround, checking this boolean in the action of the rule, but I need to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Rule example (not working):

```
rule "0 - rule1"
salience 1
lock-on-active
when
   $invoice: com.packages.object(son.isErrors == true)
then
   doSomething();
end

rule "5 - rule2"
salience 4
lock-on-active
when
   $invoice: someCondition()
then                                                                                           
 $invoice.getson().setIsErrors(true);
 update($invoice);;
end
```

Workaround:

```
rule "0 - rule1"
salience 1
lock-on-active
when
   $invoice: com.packages.object(true == true)
then
   if(son.isErrors==true)
      doSomething();
end

rule "5 - rule2"
salience 4
lock-on-active
when
    $invoice: someCondition()
then                                                                                           
 $invoice.getson().setIsErrors(true);
 update($invoice);;
end
```

I'm using Drools 7.73.0

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show your model and what is `someCondition()`. What is `com.package.object` and how does it relate to whatever class `$invoice` is?